# Rails console not running multiple lines of code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

So when I write this in my server rails console:

```
irb(main):001:0> Member.all do |member|
irb(main):002:1* member.identify
irb(main):003:1> end
```

It doesn't run the identify function, it just returns this:

```
Member Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" ORDER BY members.created_at DESC
...
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong syntax wise? How do you run multiline code in a server console?

Comment: It's not multiline issue. Use `each` to iterate over members: `Member.all.each do ....`

Comment: Is `.identify` the name of the sql function you want to apply on `Member`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply the `.identify` SQL function to `Member`, you don't need a multiline statement with `do` and `end`, you can just write:

```
Member.identify
```

`Member.all` will return an array of objects that go with the query. You typically do not need to iterate over them, as it makes more sense to write a separate query that would automatically give you what you wanted . You can put a separate function in your Model (either a class method or scope) that would give you the desired results that you want.

i.e.:

Member model:

```
self.some_method
  where(":member_name => "Jack")
end
```

and from here you can call it in your views or controllers by writing `@member = Member.some_method`

For the future if you wanted to iterate over each element within a collection (array, hash) you need to chain the object/class to an iterator such as each, or map. An iterator is basically a method that will go over each element of your collection, and apply certain methods/operations to each item in the collection:

i.e.:

```
 some object = [1,2,3]
 some_object.each do |x|
    puts x
    #will go over each element in array and print it
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the rails console (inside the app directory):

```
rails c
```

or

```
rails console
```

There you multiline will work.

Comment: Yes I am using rails c

Comment: And what brings `Member.all`?